# Regex to match all outermost pair of bracket into array

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I want a regex to match all outermost pair of bracket into array with their contents in them even if their content could be nested.
This was my code

this gives expected output

```
console.log("52*((6*8)-4+3^(7+5))".match(/ *(\([^]*\)) */g)) /* => [ '((6*8)-4+3^(7+5))' ]  correct*/
```

But

this doesn't give expected output

```
console.log("52*(6*8)-4+3^(7+5)".match(/ *(\([^]*\)) */g)) /* => [ '(6*8)-4+3^(7+5)' ] incorrect expected [ '(6*8)', '(7+5)' ]*/
```

please if anyone understand this problem help me

Comment: `\/((.*)/)\g` try that.

Comment: Apart from abusing regex features that elevate it above regular expressions, parsing nested brackets of unknown depth is impossible.

Comment: @Alex I just tried it and it still show same thing as above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

Comment: I just want to grab all outermost pair of brackets and return them with their contents

Comment: Yes, and that is already impossible.

Comment: Note: Parsing mathematical expressions is often done by evaluating the **inner**most brackets one after another, which is possible, because you don't have to care about potentially nested brackets. Using something else than regex to parse it the way you want to is an option aswell, of course.

Comment: How about a special library, e.g. [math.js](http://mathjs.org/)